# How do I pass two captured values to a Django url?

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a job request system in Django 2.0 and I need to pass two captured values to a template. This all works if I hardcode in a url that goes to an existing brand slug and category slug

urls.py:

```
    path('request/<slug:brand_slug>/<slug:category_slug>/', views.job_request_step_two, name="job_request_step_two")
```

My attempted, but failed try at setting that url dynamically in a template:

```
{% url 'form_step_two' brand.slug category.slug %}
```

Running this, I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /jobs/request/
Reverse for 'job_request_step_two' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['jobs\\/request\\/(?P<brand_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/(?P<category_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/$']
```

Comment: It looks like `brand.slug` and `category.slug` are empty can you confirm that they have values?

Comment: You were correct. I was testing that in a template that I hadn't passed that info into. Thanks!